# Can 対 be used in Japanese where "Versus" would be used in English?

Tags: translation, words, english-to-japanese

Let's say you were comparing/contrasting two concepts e.g. in a title of an essay/article.

> Concept A vs. Concept B - Which is Better?

The above is just an example.

Can 対 be used? Also, how would you put 対 in a sentence? I am guessing like this:

> ConceptA 対 ConceptB

So, is there a Japanese equivalent of "versus"? Are there different ones depending on the context?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Here in Japan these days, I actually see and hear 「[vs.]{バーサス}」 as often as or even more often than 「[対]{たい}」.

「対」 would tend to suggest a physical fight or conflict, so we tend not to use it in other contexts.

Comment: Would バーサス be a bit informal? When/in what kind of situations would you use it? I understand if it's used in a more informal context, but what about a more formal one?

Comment: To kind of rephrase that question, what would the term be in academic writing to compare two competing ideas?

Comment: I use それに対して in my academic writing or phrases like 他方. When would we use "versus" in English academic writing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's used very much like Versus. However!

As Tokyo Nagoya pointed out, バーサス is usable sometimes, too. Plus, occasionally クロス (that is, "X", usually a sign of collaboration) will be used like "Versus" depending on the context.

For example, it's "[Capcom vs. SNK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capcom_vs._SNK%3a_Millennium_Fight_2000)" in both Japan and the US, but it's "[Street Fighter X Tekken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter_X_Tekken)" in both territories.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question, pretty much.  対 is used more or less exactly like vs. is in English.

Comment: Thank you. I just wasn't sure, and didn't know where to look.